# Open Google Maps in Default Browser with Predetermined Start and End Points?

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm using Java and want to open Google Maps in my default browser with a predefined start and destination. I know how to open the home of google maps in the browser but is there any easy (or any way at all) to have my program automatically input the start and ending addresses and then select the first choice?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a link to http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=XX&daddr=XX, where saddr is the start address and daddr is the destination address. If you're using the address, make sure you URL-encode the values. You can also use latitude/longitude coordinate pairs as parameters by putting @ in front of them, like http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=@lat,long&daddr=XX.

Answer (score 1):

The URL seems to have been covered by Soemoe Aung.  As for the 'open in default browser' part, see `Desktop.browse(URI)`.

Comment: BTW - if you're undecided as to which answer to mark 'correct', please give it to Soemoe's answer.  That was a great reply.